# Why is snprintf not considered async safe?

Tags: linux, glibc, signal-handling

I was just writing some debugging in a signal handler, and noticed that from [the man7 website](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages//man7/signal-safety.7.html), snprintf is not listed as an async safe function.   I would think that this would simply modify local variables, so I'm wondering why this is not async safe?

Answer (score 1):

> why this is not async safe?

While `snprintf` (and `sprintf`) tend to work just fine in signal handlers, they are not *guaranteed* to work.

> I would think that this would simply modify local variables,

These functions may need to initialize locale machinery, which is definitely not async-signal safe.

Comment: So you're suggesting it may be using a shared global machinery where some variables are per-thread, and thus may be shared with other instances of snprintf.   With the word _tend_ are you implying that most systems they may be async safe, or are you suggesting that the race condition is so small, they _tend_ not hit it?